# How to connect FIOS in new (to us) apartment to PCs and devices

Tags: ethernet, wired-networking, wiring, fios

My roommate and I just moved into a new apartment and had Verizon FIOS set up.

We assumed that since there were several Ethernet outputs across the apartment that we would be able to just hook up our computers and other accessories to these outputs but we can't. I'm completely new to this kind of thing, and I don't know where to start looking to troubleshoot.

Comment: All your ethernet ports will link up somewhere. Often where the breaker is, there will be a patch panel. You will need a switch or hub in there for all the ports to work correctly. If you can put the fios modem in there, or close to it, that is an option, but typically, you take the closest port in the wall where the modem/router combo is and plug it in. Now, go to the patch panel and you will see which one is coming from that room w the modem. Now you can connect a switch in here and then connect the other rooms from there.

Answer (score 1):

The FIOS provider activates your media converter, a small box somewhere in the apartment attached to a fiber optic line from the wall and also attached to AC.

A) If you rent a router from them, they're responsible to connect and test that router. Here's a very rough sketch of the typical fiber-to-Ethernet-and-WiFi setup when you rent a router from them.

[image: Sketch of FIOS end user termination]

B) If you did not pay for their router rental, it's up to you to connect your router to their media converter with your Ethernet cable, and for you to connect whatever devices you wish to your router. If you do not have a router, you will need one, plus (for every PC or device) patch cables to run from the router to every device (or the the apartment patch panel or biscuit jacks [image: little biscuit-sized boxes] the little boxes taped or screwed to the wall or molding which have an 8-conductor jack inside. They don't have eight conductors? Then those are for phone lines, and you can't use them for Ethernet.)

If they *are* 8-conductor (not 6, 4, or 2 conductors, but really, truly, eight), Look on the biscuit jacks to see if they're labeled, which maybe tells you where their wires go. Could be there's a patch panel or several biscuit jacks all in one place, and if there's either, your FIOS box is probably within three feet (the distance of the commonest Ethernet cable found on a telco tech's truck).

They're not all eight pins inside the jack? They're phone connectors, and you cannot use them for Ethernet. Period.

The jacks have 8 pins, but they're not labeled? Then connect your router to each of the patch jacks or biscuits. When you do this, the light for each of the 4-8-howevermany ports on your router will all be dark.

Go to a room, connect a PC with an Ethernet cable to a wall port there, turn it on, and then go back to the router. If there's a new light on the router, you've connected; if not, tell your apartment manager his wiring's bad. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Gee, that sounds like work. How does an installer do it? They've got a [Fox-and-Hound set](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Standard-701K-G-Tone-and-Probe-Kit-701K-G/203495654) which let them trace wiring. You don't want to spend the $100 or so to get one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the being the most clear, helpful person who has ever answered a question, this was amazingly thorough.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please click on the grey up arrowhead near the top of the answer at left. If it was the best answer, also click on the checkmark to show it was the best answer. That's how we get out amazing superpowers here :).